Problem dev files
I have a problem with Ubuntu. From the moment I initialize my PC, the time changes and the connection drops. I have to refresh the time for the connection to come back. I noticed this because when I was using the ESP32, the system did not recognize the USB port anymore. I used the command ls /dev/tty* and it returned that no file was found. What should I do?
Dev Files:

